# Why the input function is not work in the spyder (Python3.9)?

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

Why the input function is not work in the spyder (Python3.9)?
#The code I typed

```
while True:
    s = input('Enter something : ')
    if s == 'quit':
        break
    print('Length of the string is', len(s))
print('Done')
```

#The console
output

```
runfile('C:/Users/85251/Documents/Year3sem1/ISEM 2006 Python/indproj/untitled1.py', wdir='C:/Users/85251/Documents/Year3sem1/ISEM 2006 Python/indproj')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\Documents\Year3sem1\ISEM 2006 Python\indproj\untitled1.py:8 in <module>
    s = input('Enter something : ')

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py:1075 in raw_input
    return self._input_request(

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py:1120 in _input_request
    raise KeyboardInterrupt("Interrupted by user") from None

KeyboardInterrupt: Interrupted by user
```

Tried to traceback, not work

Comment: KeyboardInterrupt is unrelated to your code. Please provide more information about the problem your having. What does 'not working' mean?

Comment: It works for me. There is something more that not in the post ...